# Accessing files through Google Drive picker in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

I want to select file from Google drive app and download metadata. How can i do this in iOS without querying for all files and display on my own like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213863/listing-of-all-folders-of-google-drive-through-ios-google-drive-sdk)?
 Here they have just provided picker API for webapp : https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

Comment: Any help on this question?